# Error message 'Data frame name not defined' when plotting histogram in python

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, histogram, outliers

I want to plot a histogram for all numerical columns in my data frame. An error message keeps on coming up saying my data frame name (Cab_Data) is not defined.

I have installed and imported matplotlib as plt, I used the code below to plot the histograms
`Cab_Data.hist()`

It returns the error message
NameError: name 'Cab_Data' is not defined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you upload the full code you have when creating histogram? To provide a bit more context.

Comment: If I get you correctly, here are the codes relating to the histogram. `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`, `Cab_Data.hist()`

Comment: O I got you now. That usually means you haven't fully loaded your DataFrame into the environment. Is Cab_Data loaded before calling Cab_Data.hist()?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this helped me resolve the issue. I loaded it the previously but it appears I had to reload it again for it to be recognized. Is there a way for me to define the data frame name without having to reload again, so that python easily recognizes it?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. Yup, you have to load the DataFrame in every time you load your instance of Python.